# Calling Obj-C Methods with the same signature in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm converting a half started project into Swift to get my head around the basics and quirks. I've found a bit of an issue that I'm not sure can be solved without an update/fork of the library I'm using (AFOAuth2Client).

I'm trying to call AFOAuth2Client's `authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath: scope: success: failure:` method. However, it also contains 4 other methods that start with `authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:`.

Even though my params are different, the swift compiler (Xcode Beta 2) is complaining at me saying

> "Ambiguous use of 'authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath'".

For those that need to see what I'm trying to do....

```
client.authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath(path: "string here", scope: "string here", success: { (cred: AFOAuthCredential!) -> Void in

    // Success

}, failure: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in

    // Failure

})
```

The header of AFOauth2Client defines the following problem causers...

```
- (void)authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:(NSString *)path
                                 scope:(NSString *)scope
                               success:(void (^)(AFOAuthCredential *credential))success
                               failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;

- (void)authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:(NSString *)path
                          refreshToken:(NSString *)refreshToken
                               success:(void (^)(AFOAuthCredential *credential))success
                               failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;

- (void)authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:(NSString *)path
                                  code:(NSString *)code
                           redirectURI:(NSString *)uri
                               success:(void (^)(AFOAuthCredential *credential))success
                               failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;

- (void)authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:(NSString *)path
                            parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                               success:(void (^)(AFOAuthCredential *credential))success
                               failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion to point swift to a specific method or confirm that I need to fork/alter?

Comment: what happens if you do `client.authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath("string here"` instead of `client.authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath(path: "string here"` ?

Comment: My god, it was that simple! Thanks Kreiri

Comment: @Kreiri you should write that as an actual answer so that it can be accepted

Comment: @drewag was thinking the same thing, would rather give Kreiri the reward :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`client.authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath("string here"`

instead of

`client.authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath(path: "string here"`